# Add iteratively one edge in a graph generated by a k regular game maintaining past connections

Tags: r, igraph

I have generated an undirected regular graph with an even number of nodes with the same degree, e.g. *k*, by using the function `k.regular.game` of the R package `igraph`.

Now I need to iteratively add one edge to each node, so that in each iteration the degree remains constant for every node and it is equal to *k + i*, where *i* is the number of iterations performed.

In addition, I want connections to be preserved in each iteration, that is: the set of neighbors of agent *j* for iteration *i* should be the same of the set of neighbors of agent *j* for iteration *i + 1* except for one connection: e.g., if *j* is connected to *w* and *y* when *k = 2*, *j* must be connected to *w*, *y* and *z* when *k = 3*.

My final goal is to obtain *(n-1)* graphs, where *n* is equal to the number of nodes in the regular graph. As a result, I will obtain that the first generated graph has *k = 1* and the last generated graph has *k = (n-1)*.

Any suggestion on how to do this?

Comment: I'm confused. You want to add edges one by one but the degree should remain constant for every node? That is certainly impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a nice network problem solved with two partial solutions below.

Let's imagine there is a function which would bring a graph `g` from all degrees being 1 to all degrees being 2. It would have to be a graph with an even number of nodes.

`increment.k <- function(g){}`

It follows that `increment.k` will increase the degree of each node by one by adding `|V|/2` edges to it - one edge for each two nodes in the graph. From what I understand from your problem specification, any of those edges must *not* connect agin two nodes that are already connected. This makes `increment.k()` a puzzle in which a random edge between two nodes might close the possibility for all nodes to reach the new `k`-value of degrees. What if a graph has k=1 and we start adding edges at random only to arrive at the last edge only to find that the only two nodes still with degree 1 are already connected?!

I cannot intuitively grasp if this allows for the possibility of graphs that cannot be incremented since no combination of random edges allows for the creation of `|V|/2` edges between previously unconnected nodes. But I can imagine that such graphs exist.

I've done this example on a graph with 20 nodes (which consequently can have a `k` between 1 and 19):

`g <- k.regular.game(no.of.nodes=20, k=1, directed=F)`

What if you were to generate random `k.regular.game`s with a higher k until you found a graph where the edges of your graph is a subset of the edges of the higher-k random graph? It should be spectacularly slow.

The problem, of course, is that you don't want to allow for duplicated arches. If not, the solution would be quite simple:

```
increase.k.allowing.duplicates <- function(graph){
    if(length(V(graph))%%2!=0){
        stop("k can only be incremented for graphs with an even number of nodes.")
    }
    # Add random edges to the graph and allow dual edges just to increase k
    graph %>% add_edges(as.numeric(sample(1:length(V(graph)), length(V(graph)))))
}
```

**The above code would solve the problem if double arches were allowed.** This would return graphs of ever higher k, and would let k go towards infinity since the number of nodes of the graph don't set any maximum average degree of the graph.

I have come up with this Montecarlo approach below. To increase k by one, a given number of edges is added one by one between nodes, but if the loop runs out of alternatives when placing arches between nodes that are 1) not connected and 2) not already incremented to the higher k/degree, the process of creating a new graph with a higher k starts over. The function has a maximum number of tries start over in `maximum.tries`.

```
increase.k <- function(graph, maximum.tries=200){
    if(length(V(graph))%%2!=0){
        stop("k can only be incremented for graphs with an even number of nodes.")
    }
    k <- mean(degree(graph))
    if(k != round(k) ){
        stop("Nodes in graph do not have the same degree")
    }
    if(k >= length(V(graph))-1 ) {
        stop("This graph is complete")
    }

    # each node has the following available arches before starting the iteration:
    #posisble.arches <- lapply(neighbors(graph,1), function(x) setdiff(V(graph), x[2:length(x)]))

    # Here we must lay the puzzle. If we run into a one-way street with the edges we add, we'll have to start afresh
    original.graph <- graph
    for(it in 1:maximum.tries){
        # We might need many tries to get the puzzle right by brute-forcing

        # For each try we increment in a loop to avoid duplicate links
        for(e_ij in 1:(length(V(graph))/2)){
            # Note that while(mean(degree(graph)) < k + 1){} is a logical posibility, but less safe

            # Add a new edge between two nodes of degree k. i is any such node and j is any such node not already connected to i
            i <- sample(as.numeric(V(graph)[degree(graph)==k]), 1)
            js <- as.numeric(V(graph)[degree(graph) == k * !V(graph) %in% c(as.numeric(neighbors(graph,i)), i)])
            # Abandon this try if no node unconnected to i and with degree == k exists
            if(length(js)==0){break}

            j <- sample(c(js), 1); if(length(js)==1){j<-js}
            graph <- graph %>% add_edges(c(i,j))
        }

        # Did we lay the puzzle to completion successfully crating a random graph with a higher k?
        if(mean(degree(graph)) == k+1){
            # Success
            print(paste("Succeded at iteration ", it))
            break
        } else {
            # Failure, let's try again
            graph <- original.graph
            print("Failed")
        }
    }
    (graph)
}

# Compare the two approaches
g1 <- increase.k.allowing.duplicates(g)
g2 <- increase.k(g)
degree(g1) == degree(g2)
l <- layout_with_gem(g2)
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plot(g1, layout=l, vertex.label="")
plot(g2,layout=l, vertex.label="")
dev.off()

# Note that increase.k() can be run incrementally up untill a complete graph:
is.complete <- function(graph){mean(degree(graph)) >= (length(V(graph))-1)}
while(!is.complete(g)){
    print(mean(degree(g)))
    g <- increase.k(g)
}
# and that increase.k() cannot increase k in already complete graphs.
g <- increase.k(g)
```

**The above code has solved the problem for *some* graphs**. More iterations are needed to lay the puzzle the larger the graph is. In this example with only 20 nodes, each k-level can be generated from 1-19 relatively quickly. I did manage to get 19 separate networks from `k=1` to `k=19`. But I have managed to get stuck in the loop also, which I take as evidence for the existing network structures of which k cannot be successfully incremented. Particularly since the same starting specification can get stuck sometimes, but manage to arrive at a complete graph on other occasions.

To test the function, I set the `maximum.tries` to 25 and tried to go from `k=1` to `19` 100 times. It never worked. The higher the k, the more difficult it is to lay the puzzle and find arches that fit, even though the next-to-last iteration is faster before a collapse. The risk of hitting the cap of 25 increased between the 15th and 18th iteration, and most graphs only made it to `k=17`.

[image]

It is possible to imagine this method being performed backwards starting at a complete graph, removing edges within a Montecarlo process which tries to remove edges to achieve a graph with all degrees at k-1. It should run into similar problems, though.

The code above is really an attempt to brute-force this problem without going into the underlying mathematics of graphs of this type. I am not a mathematician and lack the skills, but maybe the creation of a fail-safe `k.increment()`-function is a real and unsolved mathematical problem. If any graph-theoreticians come by this post, please enlighten us.

Comment: I really like the approach and the intuition underlying it. I am using a network with 74 nodes and it seems to be working. The process is a bit slow as you said, so let's see if someone else can come up with a more efficient code.